# How can I get a call to action link to come out on every blog post on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

When I write a blog post I want each one to display a call to action link at the bottom. But I don't want to have to worry about putting this at the bottom of every blog post I write. So is there a way I can modify the theme? I don't know alot about PHP but I have modified the header I just cant see how each blog post is created...

Thanks

UPDATE: In response to Pat Teen, he said to modify the single.php file, but there is no single.php file...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the call to action link is the same for each blog post, you can edit the PHP file responsible for generating your theme's blog posts (single.php most likely, unless there are custom post types involved).

You can find your theme's template files in the /wp-content/themes/YOUR_ACTIVE_THEME_HERE/ directory.

Open up single.php or (single-*.php depending on whether it is using custom post-types) and insert the call to action HTML in the location that you would like it to appear beneath the post.